# How to use Panorama with Forge Viewer v6

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Based on https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/iphone-panorama-forge-viewer example, I am able to use panorama on my iphone. However, when I tried to implement this extension using Forge Viewer v6, it does not work.

How do I implement this feature in v6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to some changes between the versions, the process of overriding the Gamepad behavior is now a little different:

In your HTML, include a `<script>` tag with the *FirstPerson* extension, and follow it by another `<script>` tag with the *deviceOrientationExt* extension:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v6.0"></script>
  ...
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/extensions/FirstPerson/FirstPerson.js?v=v6.0"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wallabyway/deviceOrientationExt/master/docs/deviceOrientationExt.js"></script>
</head>
```

And in your JavaScript code, activate the first person tool after loading the *FirstPerson* extension:

```
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.FirstPerson').then(function() {
    viewer.toolController.activateTool('firstperson');
});
```

Comment: original sample is now updated. sorry about that. ;-)